# Spring boot Controller Advice not getting called on Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a rest endpoints that is supposed to upload pdf files. But When I upload a large file a getting this error on post man. So I need to have my own custom error handler class and what I have its not getting invoked at all.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Forbidden</p><p><b>Description</b> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.34</h3></body></html>
```

this is my spring boot code

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(FileSizeLimitExceededException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleHugeFileUpload(FileSizeLimitExceededException e){
      
      
        return response(500, "File Exceed expected limit");
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ServerResponse> response(int code, String msg) {
        return  ResponseEntity
                .badRequest().body(new ServerResponse(code,msg
                ));
    }



}

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile)  {

        try{
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());


            String uploadDir = settingService.getSetting().getFiles_upload_dir();

            FileUploadUtil.uploadFile(uploadDir, fileName, multipartFile);

            return  ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest().body(new ServerResponse(Common.SUCCESS_CODE,Common.SUCCESS_MESSAGE
                    ));
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            Common.logException(es);
            return  ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest().body(new ServerResponse(Common.BAD_REQUEST,es.getMessage()
                    ));
        }


    }
```

and this is the log in my IDE which is thrown upon hitting the send request button on post man.
NB. when I upload a less MB file its getting uploaded successfully
am using spring boot version 2.2.11.RELEASE